RAM installation and cable management: Is it safe for my speaker cable be under or on the RAM?
I just upgraded my laptop’s RAM spec from 4GB DDR3 to 16GB DDR3 (max). The laptop is an Acer Aspire E5-576. Everything went smoothly there’s just a slight issue…
Speaker cable on RAM

This cable that connects the speakers, has been placed in such a way that it sits where only the second RAM stick is supposed to.
Should I leave it just this, sitting on the RAM, or should I place it under the Second RAM module like this…
Speaker cable under the RAM

I have tried moving the cable out of the RAM’s way but it just isn’t long or flexible enough.
I am asking the question particularly because as per my use case and climate conditions, the system runs hot and I’ve often noticed this portion of the laptop (Storage and memory) heating up with slightly heavy use. Since it’s in direct contact with the memory either way, I’m worried the heating ram modules would damage the wire over time and result in some component failure or worse. Is there any way I can prevent the direct contact and/or the heat transfer from the RAM to the speaker wire?

Honestly, it should be fine either way.  Its insulated, so nothing will short.  If you had to pick one, put it under the RAM, so when the case is reattached its not pressing down on the RAM.

...and check that no pointy bits of solder or connector look like they might be able to puncture that insulation.

Put it underneath the RAM module

This is someone else who has a configuration with factory installed two sticks and it is fine.
Examining the photos it looks as though If you disconnect the speaker cable move it to the other side of the wire above it you may be able to slide the excess wire down towards the edge of the case.
The only reason I think this is because of two other configurations I found that appear to have the wires tucked to the front of the case away from the RAM.

No RAM stick but shouldn't interfere.
Or…

Touching but not pinned over or under.

Please take a moment and spellcheck your answer. Words like “confiruation” make it difficult to read. Be sure your answer is grammatically correct.

You're right @Ramhound post has been updated
